# how to stop MPMoviePlayerViewController from downloading video if the app is in background

Tags: iphone, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller, multitasking

I use MPMoviePlayerViewController to play some videos form the internet.

When the user presses home button and the app goes in background, the iphone still downloads a lot of information.

Can anyone recomend me how the trafic can be stopped, without disabling multitasking or calling exit(0)?

I have tried to stop the MPMoviePlayerViewController, but in some cases, when the MPMoviePlayerViewController is not fully loaded, the it doesn't respond(not the video, the MPMoviePlayerViewController).

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the below delegate methods

(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application;
(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application;

(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application

Comment: Of course I use them: when I try to stop the video when the app enters in background. Anything Else?

Answer (score 0):

```
[movieplayer stop];  
movieplayer.initialPlaybackTime = -1.0;  
[movieplayer release];
```

you can use this code in **applicationDidEnterBackground**

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {  
}
```

Comment: It works is some situations, but it doesn't work in just one: when i call [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mpVC]; and the controls of MPMoviePlayerViewController didn't appeared because of slow internet, this solution doesn't work.