# iPhone close app in background: is exit(0) acceptable or something else exist?

Tags: iphone, exit, multitasking

I need to stop in some situation an application from remaining in background:
[how to stop MPMoviePlayerViewController from downloading video if the app is in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042089/how-to-stop-mpmovieplayerviewcontroller-from-downloading-video-if-the-app-is-in-b)

I don't want to disable the multitasking, but in some situation I need to close the app

`exit(0)` works perfectly, but is this approvable by Apple?
`exit(0)` doesn't create any user-experience problems, because it happens in background and the user doesn't see anything.

Does anyone know any other alternatives?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks perfectly acceptable to me. Not much difference between exit (0) and the kill -KILL of a memory warning. Provided you restore the UI to a reasonably consistent state after startup.

Of course, AppStore police might have different opinions...

Comment: I will se what apple is going to say.

Answer (score 3):

No, that's not allowed and you should give the user full control when to exit your app.

> **Don’t Quit Programmatically**
>
> Never quit an iOS application
>   programmatically because people tend
>   to interpret this as a crash. However,
>   if external circumstances prevent your
>   application from functioning as
>   intended, you need to tell your users
>   about the situation and explain what
>   they can do about it. Depending on how
>   severe the application malfunction is,
>   you have two choices.
>
> Display an attractive screen that
>   describes the problem and suggests a
>   correction. A screen provides feedback
>   that reassures users that there’s
>   nothing wrong with your application.
>   It puts users in control, letting them
>   decide whether they want to take
>   corrective action and continue using
>   your application or press the Home
>   button and open a different
>   application
>
> If only some of your application's
>   features are not working, display
>   either a screen or an alert when
>   people activate the feature. Display
>   the alert only when people try to
>   access the feature that isn’t
>   functioning.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html